# мне нужна помощь в оптимизации сайта на телефоне, при отдаление экрана есть пустое место, мне нужно это исправить

Tags: html, css

на скриншоте есть выделенные места которые мне нужно убрать, и оптимизировать сайт на маленьких экранах, желательно сделать так, что бы на телефоне нельзя было отдалять  https://bluecoc.online/index.html - вот сайт, надеюсь поможете[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Используй готовые библиотеки например тот же [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) от Twitter тогда с адаптированием утебя проблем не будет

Comment: это конечно хорошо, но я бы хотел научится, что бы сам решать эту пробему, но я не понимаю из-за чего это может быть, мне нужно узать как это произошло